# ADODB / SQL Server mssql_execute stored procedure fails but works if debug is set to true

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds, adodb-php

I am connecting to a SQL Server database from PHP using ADODB. I have several stored procedures that I have been executing just fine. The last call that I have created for some reason keeps failing. I put debug as true and it works just fine. I have no idea why this would be happening.

here is the error I get

```
Error: mssql_execute() [<a href='function.mssql-execute'>function.mssql-execute</a>]:      stored procedure execution failed  in /path/to/adodb/lib/adodb5/drivers/adodb-mssql.inc.php on line 768
```

Here is the method I created to pass all my stored procedures to, like I said it works fine with other stored procedures but this one and I have double checked that all the spellings of the parameters and stored procedure are correct.

```
protected function _getSpArray($db, $sp, array $spParams) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->PrepareSP($sp);
        foreach ($spParams as $param) {
            $db->InParameter($stmt, $param[0], $param[1]);
        }
        $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rs = $db->Execute($stmt);
        $rsArray = array();
        if (!$rs) {
            echo 'No records found \n';
            return;
        }
        else {
            foreach ($rs as $k => $row) {
                $rsArray[$k] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $rsArray;
    } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It is failing on this line #768 of adodb5/drivers/adodb-mssql.inc.php

```
$rez = mssql_execute($sql[1]);
```

and the sql array has these values

```
[0] stored_procedure_name
[1] resource id='657' type='mssql statement'
```

I have seen the following comments on PHP.net, I changed my freetds host name to be something different then the IP address and still nothing. I am not sure about the free result since I am using adodb.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php#93938

I am using adodb 5.11

Comment: Maybe you should give a little bit more error information? "execution failed" is NOT what SQL Server says, it provides a much better explanation. PHP somehow should expose this.

Comment: I am looking at the SQL Server Profiler and it doesn't even seem to get there. I am not sure how to debug the adodb library any more than what I have. I wish I could find more of an error but that is all I can find

Comment: You should add the version of ADODB you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set debug as true ADODB uses other function to execute the statement. In this case `function _adodb_debug_execute(&$zthis, $sql, $inputarr)`

If debug is set to false ADODB uses `function &_Execute($sql,$inputarr=false)`. When you check the source for both methods you can clearly see the difference.

```
<?php
function _adodb_debug_execute(&$zthis, $sql, $inputarr)
{
    //ADODB prepares debug information dump...

    $qID = $zthis->_query($sql,$inputarr);

    //Here ADODB makes the difference

    if ($zthis->databaseType == 'mssql') { 
    // ErrorNo is a slow function call in mssql, and not reliable in PHP 4.0.6
        if($emsg = $zthis->ErrorMsg()) {
            if ($err = $zthis->ErrorNo()) ADOConnection::outp($err.': '.$emsg);
        }
    } else if (!$qID) {
        ADOConnection::outp($zthis->ErrorNo() .': '. $zthis->ErrorMsg());
    }

    if ($zthis->debug === 99) _adodb_backtrace(true,9999,2);
    return $qID;
}
?>
```

Here is the _Execute function

```
<?php
function &_Execute($sql,$inputarr=false){
        //Here ADODB chooses which fn to use
        if ($this->debug) {
            global $ADODB_INCLUDED_LIB;
            if (empty($ADODB_INCLUDED_LIB)) include(ADODB_DIR.'/adodb-lib.inc.php');
            $this->_queryID = _adodb_debug_execute($this, $sql,$inputarr);
        } else {
            $this->_queryID = @$this->_query($sql,$inputarr);
        }
        //...

        if ($this->_queryID === false) { // error handling if query fails
            //If debug ADODB prints backtrace regardless the result
            if ($this->debug == 99) adodb_backtrace(true,5);    
            $fn = $this->raiseErrorFn;
            if ($fn) {
                $fn($this->databaseType,'EXECUTE',$this->ErrorNo(),$this->ErrorMsg(),$sql,$inputarr,$this);
            } 
            $false = false;
            //Returns false no matter what...
            return $false;
        } 
        //...
    }
?>
```

Try adding this to your script to test the behaviour of the script and keep in mind that if the execute fails it will return a `false` value. So take care with the returned value.

```
protected function _getSpArray($db, $sp, array $spParams) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->PrepareSP($sp);
        foreach ($spParams as $param) {
            $db->InParameter($stmt, $param[0], $param[1]);
        }
        $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rs = $db->Execute($stmt);
        $rsArray = array();
        if (!$rs) {
            echo 'No records found \n';
            return;
        }
        else {
            foreach ($rs as $k => $row) {
                $rsArray[$k] = $row;
            }
        }
        //add this line to free the resources after use. 
        mssql_free_result($rs);
        return $rsArray;
    } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I tried adding that right after the execute and it didn't do anything. I am going to try and debug and see the difference.

Comment: Ok so at home it worked but when I got into work today it doesn't. I really don't get this. It's only 1 stored procedure out of the 10 I have been calling. I don't get why it would be a freetds thing or the have to free the result if I didn't have to on the others. I also don't see the difference in what the two methods do obviously one prints out the information but they both call the same query method.

Comment: &_Execute returns false on $this->_queryID === false (strict equallity check for type) checks for type boolean and false. The other returns _query value without check, that is the difference. What is the environmental differences between your home and your work?

Comment: Nothing much, I am using the same computer but connecting through a VPN. I'll have to double check tonight when I get home that it was actually doing that, maybe I missed it because I just checked real quick. But you can see that I did get it working in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after finding the php.net comments, even though my freetds wasn't setup with the proper name, I was using the ip address. I also wasn't using the V 8.0 I was using 7.0 and everything was working fine up until this point with the store procedures. I tried the mssql_free_result solution provide in the comments and DarkThrones answer and that didn't work but when I used adodb's close() method it is working. It uses free result and passes a query id.

If someone can comment as to why this is necessary that would be great. Is it because I was using up  to much memory or something?